# remove a string with {{ xxx }} inside another string

Tags: regex, preg-match

This is a stupid question but I would like to remove {{Lien web ....}} (including brakets) inside a string.

Example :

```
test {{Lien web|xyz}} test {{xyz}} test
```

Result should be :

```
test test {{xyz}} test
```

I tried with :

```
preg_replace('/\{\{.*?\}\}\s*/s','',$string);
```

but how to add "Lien web" ?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: regex `\{\{[^{}]*Lien web[^{}]*\}\}`, replace with empty string.

Comment: Are you trying to remove the first instance or exactly with "Lien web" inside?

Comment: indeed my pattern works but I would like to add "Lien web", any idea?

Comment: @hwnd : the instance with "Lien web", any idea?

Comment: thank you all of you, finally I took the solution of Dmitry, works like a charm!:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex is `\{\{Lein web[^\}]*]\}\}` and the respective preg_replace:

```
preg_replace('/\{\{Lien web[^\}]*\}\}/','',$string, -1);
```

The last -1 replaces all {{Lien web...}} occurrences

Comment: and I would like to remove also all strings like that :
    
    <ref name=xxxxx\>

I tried but it doesn't work:

    preg_replace('/\<ref name=[^\}]*\/\>','',$r, -1);

any idea?

Comment: The regex is `<ref name=[^>]*>` (https://regex101.com/r/hO7aY0/1). So `preg_replace('/\<ref name=[^\>]*\>','',$r, -1);`

Comment: the last "/" was missing, but it works, thank you very much Dmitry!! and also for this usefull link

Comment: You're welcome! As of useful links, there are a number of them in the end of this page http://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info (let alone plenty of other useful info).

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
preg_replace('/\{\{Lien web[^\}]*\}\}/','',$string,-1);
```

Comment: I would like also to remove all strings like that inside the string :
    
    <ref name=xxxxx\>

any idea?